# It doesn't return rows store from c#

Tags: c#, .net, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am working with Oracle and C#, when I run my stored procedure from C#, it doesn't return any results. I don't know if it is my stored procedure that I am doing it wrong or my code but it does not return results.

C# code

```
public DataTable ObtenerInformacion(string SEC)
{
    using (OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection("CONNECTION LIFETIME=10;DATA SOURCE=AAA;MAX POOL SIZE=10;PASSWORD=AAA;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=AAA"))
    {
        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        cmd.InitialLONGFetchSize = 1000;
        cmd.CommandText = "sp_student";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("SEQ", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = SEC;

        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Stored procedure code in Oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure sp_student(SEQ IN VARCHAR2)
as
 SEQUENCIA transaction.SEQ%Type;
 IMPORTE100 transaction.AMOUNT_BEFORE_DISCOUNT%Type;
 IMPORTEDESC transaction.AMOUNT_REAL%Type;
Begin
   SELECT SEQ,AMOUNT_BEFORE_DISCOUNT, AMOUNT_REAL INTO SEQUENCIA,IMPORTE100,IMPORTEDESC FROM transaction WHERE SEQ=SEQ;
end;
```

Comment: Have you run the stored procedure directly?

Comment: @insane_developer yes and returns rows correctly

Comment: The sproc name in the code doesn't match the name of the script you provided. Is that supposed to be the same?

Comment: @insane_developer It's the same name, only that I put a shorter name

Comment: Did you forgot executing this cmd.ExecuteReader()?

Comment: ** My bad on this first comment since you already using an adapter. By the way have you tried using DataSet instead of DataTable when calling da.Fill()? Then get datatable from the DataSet instead?